# How to Reset/Remove BIOS Password on the HP Laptop/ PC

Tags: windows-7

Do you know the importance of BIOS password on our computer? Do you know how to reset or remove BIOS password on the HP Laptop/PC? Can you give me some tips about how to reset BIOS password in efficient way?

Comment: Cannot be reset by clearing cmos, enter a wrong password 3 times, it should output a code, post the code and i will generate you a master password to get you into the bios and clear the password.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways of doing it, depending of constructor...

3 methods:

- Find the `CLR BIOS`, `CLEAR BIOS`, `CLR CMOS`, `CLEAR CMOS`, `RESET BIOS` or `RESET CMOS` switch on your motherboard, it's normally near the button battery. If it's a 3 pin, switch to the other 2 pin, wait, switch back. For a two pin switch, place it on both pin, wait, switch back
- Removes the button battery for a couple of second
- Some laptop can be reset by removing the battery and press the power button for 5 secondes

Comment: Wont work on a HP, its stored in a separate firmware and cannot be erased by clearing cmos.

Comment: Well not necesarily. On many HP models users are allowed the choice between "stringent" password and normal one. Normal one is deletable via clear cmos, stringent one is stored seperately as you said. Maybe he's in luck.

Comment: OP did not gives his HP model, so I gave the generic solution that should work for most PC. There is still plenty of way for doing it for HP pc ...